# Two pipelines, single zip file

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

**The scenario:**
There are two azure pipelines for UI code and .NET data service code.  There are Dev, UAT and Production releases for each pipeline.

Currently, each pipeline puts the code into its own drop folder.

**What I need to do is this:**
When the UAT release has been built, I need to zip the UI and Dataservice, then put them into a single zip file so I need to have these steps automated.

I have no prior knowledge using azure pipelines, I'm not sure where to start looking on how to achieve the above?

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it will be hugely appreciated.   Thank you so much.